# Retrieve value of a table and using the value in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm beginner in SQL Server 2012; I need to generate a `product ID` in a stored procedure, I generated part of the ID in C#, that part of ID includes `Industrialist ID` and I pass this to my stored procedure. In the stored procedure I need the last product of my Industrialist number and save in to as SQL variable on my stored procedure. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to pass items between SQL and C#, you could use an [output parameter](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/539269/outputplusparameterplusinplusstoredplusprocedurepl) where you will populate the parameter within the stored procedure.

```
string variableName;
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("**connection string**"))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("storedProcedureName", conn))
{
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("inputParameter", inputParameter);
    var outputParameter = new SqlParameter(){
        ParameterName="ParameterName"
        ,Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
        ,SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar
        ,DbType = DbType.VarChar
    };
    conn.Open();
    try
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        variableName = string.Format("{0}", outputParameter.Value);
    }
    catch{}
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

You could return the value using something along the lines of `RETURN @returnValue` in your procedure, or you could return it within a table.

```
string variableName;
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("**connection string**"))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("storedProcedureName", conn))
{
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("inputParameter", inputParameter);
    conn.Open();
    try
    {
        using (var dbReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (dbReader.Read())
            {
                variableName = string.Format("{0}", dbReader["ColumnName"]);
            }
        }
    }
    catch{}
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

A generic example of a stored procedure which might work:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[storedProcedureName]
    @InputParameter VARCHAR
    ,@OutputParameter VARCHAR OUTPUT
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @insertedId INT;
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        INSERT INTO TableName (...Column Names...) 
        VALUES (... Values...)
        SET @insertedId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    COMMIT
    SELECT @OutputParameter = ColumnName 
    FROM TableName
    WHERE IdColumnName = @insertedId
END
```

**EDIT: Possibly more relevant:**

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[storedProcedureName]
    @IndustrialistId INT
    ,@OutputParameter VARCHAR OUTPUT -- This might be an int, but it's unclear what you want
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @productId INT;
    SELECT @productId = MAX(ProductId) 
    FROM  Products 
    WHERE IndustrialistId = @IndustrialistId;

    SET @OutputParameter = CONVERT(VARCHAR,@IndustrialistId) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@productId)
END
```

If you were to provide some code it might be easier for someone to give you a more tailored response. None of the above code has been syntax checked etc. so should be considered more pseudo code but hopefully it gives you something to work with.